# IONIC/Cordova iOS inappbrowser cookies getting cleared on app close

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser

I have an ionic application which opens the browser for a functionality and when user logs in once, the cookie is saved in the inappbrowser till its lifetime. Now, in Android, Cookies are saved properly even when app is closed and restarted.

But, in iOS, cookies gets cleared once the app is closed. Is there a way to save the session cookies after the app being closed.

i have set the below options

```
var options = "location=yes,hidden=yes,clearcache=no,clearsessioncache=no";
```

Thanks